# Can I not just pack up a Docker image and bring it over to my server?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm well aware of how you [deploy your own Docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/), but I think in my case this might be an overkill. I was wondering if there is a way of packing up an image I build on one machine, and unpacking it in the server, ready for docker consumption? (aka, no need to pull it, just run it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, check out docker's save/load and import/export command pairs. They both have the functionality you're looking for, with slightly different functionality. You'll need to read the docs to see which is more suitable for your requirements.

In short, they allow you to save a docker image as a tarball, move it to another system and then import it.

Comment: Thanks, I had completely overlooked those commands. After spending weeks on other parts of the docs, I didn't feel like I could dive any more into them :)